# Merge XML elements

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<Books>
    <Title>Book 1</Title>
    <Author>A</Author>
</Books>
<Books>
    <Title>Book 2</Title>
    <Author>B</Author>
</Books>
```

Output:

```
<Books>
    <Title>Book 1</Title>
    <Author>A</Author>
    <Title>Book 2</Title>
    <Author>B</Author>
</Books>
```

I would like to write in C# to get the result as the Output, what should I do?

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve this? Where is your c# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example `newDoc` will contain what you want

```
var xml = @"
<xml>
    <Books>
        <Title>Book 1</Title>
        <Author>A</Author>
    </Books>
    <Books>
        <Title>Book 2</Title>
        <Author>B</Author>
    </Books>
</xml>";

var originalElements = XDocument.Parse(xml).Root.Elements("Books").Descendants();
var newDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Books", originalElements));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create this class :

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Books")]
    public class Books {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Title")]
        public List<string> Title { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Author")]
        public List<string> Author { get; set; }
    }

}
```

And parse your XML with [XMLReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But your XML is not really well formed.
I recommand something like that :

```
<Books>
<Book>
<Title>Book 1</Title>
    <Author>A</Author>
</Book>
<Book>    
    <Title>Book 2</Title>
    <Author>B</Author>
    </Book>
 </Books>
```

Comment: There is no need for books and book tags.  Don't agree that is not well formed.

Comment: Xavier W. - thanks for your suggestion if my XML output like that then it's not valid against XSD